# Correct Order to play ALL Half-Life games

Tags: half-life-series

**I fully understand that posts have been made that already address this question. Just give me a chance to differentiate.**

I am in love with the Half-Life series ever since I finished the first game (Half-Life 1).

I bought the rest of the Half-Life series on Steam. I want to play ALL of them, no matter if it is source, a tech demo, a multiplayer game, or a fan-made remake. I was just wondering what order I should go about playing them.

So far, the recommendations I have read do not include all of the games from Steam.

The games I have are:

- <s>Half-Life</s> -- *[finished already]*
- Half-Life: Opposing Force
- Half-Life: Blue Shift
- Half-Life: Source
- Half-Life Deathmatch: Source
- Half-Life 2
- Half-Life 2: Lost Coast
- Half-Life 2: Episode One
- Half-Life 2: Episode Two
- Half-Life 2: Deathmatch
- Black Mesa

*(I have already played Portal and Portal 2, if that is useful info)*

Thanks, I really appreciate your feedback

Comment: You're asking the same thing, I'm afraid.  Unfortunately, we don't allow duplicates, even if answers are missing things you want to know.

Comment: @Frank Thanks for letting me know, I'll try my best to piece things together on my own. Have a great day :)

Comment: @Frank I would argue that it would likely be the other way around? This question is more complete than the other - (for a terrible analogy) the other question is asking about apples and pears, whereas this question is asking about apples, pears, oranges, and grapes? There's no way that a person asking *this* question can gain an answer a question that is only addressing half of what they're asking?

Comment: @Ben The question is the same.  The answers may not address all the various games, but the question wants to know the same thing.  That's an argument for updating the answer, not asking it again.

Comment: @JohnDoe if you do find a specific order - feel free to add/update the answer to the original question :)

Comment: I have updated my answer to the original question with the additional games you mention. I have also added an excerpt on recommended order, if you wish to follow story. As past following the story, we cant really recommend an order based off our opinion, as opinion is too broad and generally off-topic. I would recommend you play the other titles completely at your discretion, perhaps starting with the earlier releases, so you are less critical of older functionality.

Comment: Make sure you scroll allll the way down. I was a late answer, so it's right at the bottom, but I also agreed that the current top answers on the original were missing quite a bit.

Comment: Also bear in mind that "sequentially", many of the games are simply not. For example, you list Half Life Source and Black Mesa. Source is a "remake" of half life, that was received by the community as 'half-done'. Consequently, fans started to make Black Mesa, which is another remake of Half-Life. My only advice is *take your time*. We may have another 5-10 years+ before another Half Life game comes out.